# How to add iphone5 device in image.xcassets Xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm actually making an IOS application and i have a problem with the portability on my difference devices.
I'm using Xcode 7 and when i look for Images.xcassets I have this display

[image]

After some research on the web i found that

- 1x for Iphone 2G, 3G, 3GS
- 2x for Iphone 4/4s, 5/5s, 6/6s
- 3x for Iphone 6+/6s+

Found on this link: [Iphone devices sizes](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions)

I would like to know if it's possible to add a x2 that will be use only for iphone5/5s ? And how to do it with Xcode 7.0.1 because in the left panel i have only these options:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode does not allow icons for specific devices, only for their screen types.  Not sure why you would even want to do this though, you want a recognizable icon to span across all the devices, and the changing in the size should be used to sharpen an image, not have it as a different one.

Comment: It's not for an icon that i need it, but more for a background image of a view controller. That can be resized correctly on differents devices

Comment: oh, my bad, thought you wanted to do it for the icon.  For a view controller, you set the image to the larger phone size, then in your view controller panel you switch the mode to something other than scaling, depending on your needs.  if you need 2 different sized images, then you need 2 different image assets

Comment: When thinking of the image assets, keep in mind that the image is suppose to be the same set of points regardless of device, the only thing that should be changing is the pixels inside the points. (1x = 1 pixel per point, 2x = 4 pixels per point [2 width, 2 height], 3x = 9 pixels per point [3 width, 3 height])

Comment: Thank you for your help i could find an other way to solve my problem